# Place company name directly below title in edit cv

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The company name looks odd as it hits another line on the edit cv page.

Can the actual company name be placed either directly above or below the title of the candidate.

Notice in this screen shot the arrows point to the company name.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're seeing a large volume of folk with long position titles and company names like yours. I am moving this to it's own separate line below the position title.

Just pushed a fix for this, coming in the next build!

Comment: That's a good move - thank you!